# Query for size of red component of default framebuffer

Tags: opengl

Here is some code that's supposed to output the size of the red component of the default framebuffer's left back color attachment:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "vect2.h"

using namespace std;

void outputError() {
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    switch (error) {
    case GL_NO_ERROR:
        cout << "GL_NO_ERROR" << endl;
        break;
    case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
        cout << "GL_INVALID_ENUM" << endl;
        break;
    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
        cout << "GL_INVALID_VALUE" << endl;
        break;
    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
        cout << "GL_INVALID_OPERATION" << endl;
        break;
    case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
        cout << "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION" << endl;
        break;
    case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
        cout << "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "UNKNOWN ERROR: " << error << endl;
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();

    GLint size = 0;

    outputError();
    glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_BACK_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_RED_SIZE, &size);
    outputError();

    return 0;
}
```

The console output is:

```
GL_NO_ERROR
GL_INVALID_ENUM
```

Meaning there is a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error state set from my call to `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv`.  What parameter is wrong here?

EDIT: If I run this code in the `main` function, requesting the same (red) component from a custom FBO instead of the default framebuffer, then there is no error and I get the expected `32` in the `size` variable.  This means that not only are the *attachments* different when the default framebuffer is bound vs when an FBO is bound, but the *parameters* that can be queried for are also different.  So basically the question is: what parameters can be queried for using this function when the default framebuffer is bound?

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboColor);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColor);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, 800, 600);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColor);
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_RED_SIZE, &size);
```

Comment: I just tried, and it works for me quite well.Returns 8 bits for RED. Make sure your GL context is valid and alive.

Comment: run your program in CodeXL or gDEBugger and break on error. then backtrace to the exact call failing. It is never the second error's fault.

Comment: First GL error was due to my using an old version of glew.  Updated glew to 2.1.0, and the first error went away; I have updated the question accordingly.  However, the second error persists.  Ran the program in CodeXL (gDEBugger server was down when I went to download it) with "Break on OpenGL error" on.  At the breakpoint, the top of the backtrace is an address in `main.exe` (alas, I couldn't get mingw to build with debug symbols usable by CodeXL), and the latest GL call is `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` - not particularly helpful.